# Background image doesn't fill the entire page

Tags: html, css

I want to have my background as gradient and the image on top of the gradient, it worked just fine until I set overflow to auto since my div tag expands on mobile view which makes overflow hidden for the html tag not reliable so I made the image as a tag

```css
.background_image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I have made the image's position fixed so it keeps following the scroll position which wasn't exactly what I needed but It'll do.

**EDIT 2**

The problem was I was using linear gradient bg on behalf of the image which was a tag inside the body element, i fixed it by letting that image at fixed position and the change bg to radial gradient and making that gradient only styling the body tag which did solve the whole problem

Comment: You can use object fit css property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: can you please share your code and generate a small demo here so I can help you.
I am confuse a little right now.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bg"></div>

  <p>This example creates a full page background image. Try to resize the browser window to see how it always will cover the full screen (when scrolled to top), and that it scales nicely on all screen sizes.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort of helping but I think I solved it myself, Im editing my post rn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background with url property:

```
.background_image {
  background: url(YOUR_IMAGE_URL) no-repeat center center fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```